# thrust cuda, using tuple in lambda

Tags: cuda, tuples, thrust

My code is compiling and linking good, but the results are wrong. I do not understand why lambda function is not changing the tupla values. here the sample.

```
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

int main(void)
{
    // allocate storage
    thrust::device_vector<float> A(5);
    thrust::device_vector<float> B(5);
    thrust::device_vector<float> C(5);
    thrust::device_vector<float> D(5);

    // initialize input vectors
    A[0] = 3;  B[0] = 6;  C[0] = 2; 
    A[1] = 4;  B[1] = 7;  C[1] = 5; 
    A[2] = 0;  B[2] = 2;  C[2] = 7; 
    A[3] = 8;  B[3] = 1;  C[3] = 4; 
    A[4] = 2;  B[4] = 8;  C[4] = 3; 
    auto start_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(A.begin(), B.begin(),
    C.begin(), D.begin()));
    auto end_zip =thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(A.end(),   B.end(), 
    C.end(),   D.end()));

    thrust::for_each(thrust::device, start_zip, end_zip, 
      [=] __device__ (thrust::tuple<float , float , float , float> t) {
             float myval = thrust::get<0>(t) + thrust::get<1>(t) * thrust::get<2>(t);
             thrust::get<3>(t) = myval;
             printf("Call for value : %d\n", myval);
      }
    );


    // print the output
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       std::cout << A[i] << " + " << B[i] << " * " << C[i] << " = " << D[i] << 
       std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it was solved doing:

```
[=] __device__ (thrust::tuple<float , float , float , **float&> t**) {
```